# Get access to tab element inside a modal in ng-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap with Angular 2. I can't access to the `#tabs` variable from my component using `@ViewChild`. This only happens when I use the tab directive inside the modal directive. Here is my code:

> auth.component.html

```
<template #modal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="close()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ngb-tabset #tabs="ngbTabset" (tabChange)="changeTabs($event)">
                <ngb-tab title="Login" id="login">
                    <template ngbTabContent>
                        ...
                    </template>
                </ngb-tab>
                <ngb-tab title="Sign up" id="signUp">
                    <template ngbTabContent>
                       ...
                    </template>
                </ngb-tab>
            </ngb-tabset>                
        </div>
    </template>
```

> auth.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'st-auth',
    templateUrl: 'auth.component.html'
})

export class AuthComponent {

    /*
     * ------------ FIELDS -----------------
     */

    @ViewChild('modal') modal;
    private modalElement:any;

    @ViewChild('tabs') tabs;
    private tabsElement:any;


    /*
     * ------------ INITIALIZE -----------------
     */

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.modalElement = this.modal;
        this.tabsElement = this.tabs;

        console.log(this.tabs); //show 'undefined'
    }

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
}
```

Comment: I guess your modal isn't visible (and not added to DOM). So you can't get access to that `#tabs`, cause its not present at this time! :)

Comment: Yes, but what can I do to get access to `#tabs` from the Component??

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. When using a < template > element, angular does not treat this as a normal DOM element, so you cannot access it via the ViewChild decorator. What I ended up doing was to create a new component with the dialog content and passed this component to modalService.open(). An example can be seen [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/modal/demos/component/plnkr.html).

*Hint: Don't forget to add your modal-component to the entryComponents array of your module*

Answer (score 0):

Try using an variable "active: boolean" and function "changeTabs()" to change value active, ex:

HTML:

```
<tabset>
       <tab id="tab1" [disabled]="activeTab"  [active]="!activeTab">....</<tab>
       <tab id="tab2" [disabled]="!activeTab"  [active]="activeTab">....</<tab>
</tabset>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="changeTabs()"> ChangeTab</button>
```

TS

```
activeTab: boolean = false;

changeTabs(){
    this.activeTab= !this.activeTab;
}
```